# Proper way to override methods with minor changes in Python

Tags: python, oop, subclass, overriding

Say I have a class

```
class Base(object):
    def my_method(self, input):
        print input #suppose this is many lines
        print "mymethod" #so is this
```

and a subclass that has a method which does almost the same thing, except for an extra operation in the *middle* of the method, e.g.

```
class Sub(Base):
    def mymethod(self, input): #how do I properly define this?
        print input 
        print "some other stuff" #additional operation in the middle
        print "mymethod"
```

What is the proper way to overriding `mymethod`?

- Do I copy-and-paste the majority of `Base.mymethod()`? (Probably not - that definitely violates DRY).
- Do I define `Base.mymethod()` to have a conditional statement for the additional operation that only returns true in a subclass case? (Probably not - that doesn't make sense since the base class should be standalone and this seems like a recipe for disaster)
- Can I somehow use `super()`? (Seems not - `Sub`'s additional operation is in the middle of the method, not the beginning or end)

Comment: DRY is pretty strict but just because two blocks of code are the same/copied doesn't mean it violates DRY. They must also be used for the same reasons and change for the same reasons. Otherwise, they're not actually the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a simple example, I will most likely copy these three small lines, even if creates a repetitions. Try to avoid [over-engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering).

In the case where `my_method()` is actually more complex, you can divide your function into three steps, and let the child classes overload the part they want.

```
class Base(object):

    def my_method(self, input):
        self._preprocess(input)
        self._process()
        self._postprocess()

    def _preprocess(self, input):
        print(input)

    def _process(self):
        pass

    def _postprocess(self):
        print("mymethod")


class Sub(Base):

    def _process(self):
        print("some other stuff")
```

Of course you should use more meaningful method names.

Comment: It’s worth noting that on the rare occasions where you need this, you also often need `super` as well—e.g., some subclass has a `_preprocess` that first calls `super()._preprocess()` and then does other stuff. But the nice thing is that if you break things up properly like this, it just works, with or without super as appropriate to each subclass.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on where stuff belongs. Usually if you end up wanting to insert stuff in between operations of the base's method, it means that method should actually be split into several methods.

For instance:

```
class Base(object):
    def my_method(self, input):
        print input #suppose this is many lines
        print "mymethod" #so is this
```

could become:

```
class Base(object):
    def my_method(self, input):
        self.do_first_thing(input)
        self.do_second_thing("mymethod")

    def do_first_thing(self, input):
        print(input)

    def do_second_thing(self, data):
        print(data)
```

This lets subclasses redefine the whole process without having to re-implement each step. The concept is akin to a [template method](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method), but backwards.

(Normally the point of a template method pattern is to let subclasses redefine steps, here we use the same structure to let subclasses redefine the template itself).